# Tile repair project: what am I working with here? What's the best way to get a flat surface for mounting?

Tags: tile, masonry, grout, cement

I’m working on a few projects around the house right now and one of them is fixing tiles that have come loose in the entryway over the years.

To get a better idea of what I’m working with, I wanted to see what was underneath the tile. It appears to be more than just thin-set; I vaguely remember seeing this sort of mesh screen as a mount for stucco on houses. What’s the best way to get a surface that is suitable for re-mounting the tiles? The house was built in 1958, if that helps at all.

[image]

Comment: TCNA F141 or F145 https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/261810/18078 https://imiweb.org/06-130-0103-tile-floor-tile-mortar-bed-plywood/

Comment: @Ecnerwal hmmm, so the strategy would be to fill in my hole, grind down what little thinset there is, and just remount it. Any thoughts beyond that?